# power series & convergence radius for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How can I develop following functions around the given development point z0 into a power series and determine their radius of convergence?

a) $z_0=3$ ,$$\frac{1}{5-z}$$
b) $z_0=0$, $$\cos(z)^3$$

---

a) $$\frac{1}{5-z}=\frac{1}{5*(1-\frac{z}{5})}$$
How can I develop the function in a power series for $z_0 \neq 0$?

b) $$ \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\ x^{2n}(3+3^{2n})}{(2n)!}\ $$
Can I transform this further? Is the convergence radius infinity?

Comment: Let's not make up identities like $\frac1{5-z}=\frac15\cdot \left(1-\frac z5\right)$.

Comment: If the function has $z$ in it, the series should not have $x$ in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You can do\begin{align}\frac1{5-z}&=\frac1{2-(z-3)}\\&=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z-3}2}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-3)^n}{2^{n+1}},\end{align}if $|z-3|<2$.

b) Your computations are fine. And, since that's the sum of two power series that are convergent everywhere, it's also convergent everywhere.